# Areas of Projections of a Rectangular Prism

Tags: spherical-coordinates, solid-geometry

How do I find the areas of the three projections (onto the xy, xz, and yz planes) of a rectangular prism, given it's dimensions (L, W, H), and θ and ϕ (conventional spherical angles of its rotation)?

Say when θ = 0 and ϕ = 0, L aligns with the x-axis, W with y, and H with z.

Simple problem, tough solution.

Comment: You may find so of the strategies used in [this somewhat related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2836827/projecting-a-surface-on-another-surface) helpful.